# laravel 5 ,requested url was not found on this server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I am trying to upload my laravel 5 project on **Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server** at xxx.xx.x.xx **Port 80**.

When i browse my site using **xxx.xx.x.xx/project/public** , landing page is working fine.

But when i tried to log in , it throws this error ,

The requested URL **xxx.xx.x.xx/project/public/auth/login** was not found on this server.

but when i tried this **xxx.xx.x.xx/project/public/index.php/auth/login** it throws View [app] not found.

I tried using **RewriteBase** on **htaccess** file also edited **public/index.php** file and changed these following lines...

**require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';**
to **require __DIR__.'/../project/public/bootstrap/autoload.php';**

and

**$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';**

to **$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project/public/bootstrap/app.php';**

nothing is working!!

I know this one is older topic but i didn't find solution.

Looking for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Laravel are you working on? I've got problem with auth on 5.1 LTS. No problem with standard configuration (never touched htaccess or config file).

I can suggest to try a new install with a new Laravel package on your server without modifications and see if it works.

This may help: [Laravel 5.1 Authentication documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization)

Comment: Already tried with new source but not working, I am using Laravel 5.

Comment: You can try this tutorial: [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-laravel-5s-authentication-facade--cms-23461)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Apache rewrite module. Run this in command line:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and don't forget to restart Apache after.

```
service apache2 restart
```